# Definition of a fusion sequence and proof of the fusion lemma.

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I was reading Sacks forcing from Jech's Multiple Forcing and reached the definition of a fusion sequence which said:

---

> Definition. $p \le_n q$ means $p \le q$ and every nth branching point of $q$ is a branching point of $p$. And we call a sequence $\{p_n\}_{n \in \omega}$ a fusion sequence if: $p_0 \ge_0 p_1 \ge_1 \dots \ge_{n-1} p_n \ge_n \dots$

---

And then i tried to prove the fusion lemma and i came up short. So naturally i checked Jech's Set Theory but there he defined a fusion sequence like this:

---

> Definition. $p \le_n q$ means $p \le q$ and every nth branching point of $q$ is **an nth** branching point of $p$. And we call a sequence $\{p_n\}_{n \in \omega}$ a fusion sequence if: $p_0 \ge_0 p_1 \ge_1 \dots \ge_{n-1} p_n \ge_n \dots$

---

So which definition is correct? And for the fusion lemma the only part which i can prove is that the intersection is downward closed... I would really appreciate any hints that would help me prove the intersection is a perfect tree.
Thanks for your patience.

---

**Edit I**: I forgot the statement of the fusion lemma:

> Lemma. If $\{p_n\}_{n \in \omega}$ is a fusion sequence, then $p = \cap_{n \in \omega} p_n$ is a perfect tree. Moreover, $p \le_n p_n$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two are actually equivalent.
Every branching point of $p$ is certainly a branching point of $q$ and the first version says that every $n$th branching point of $q$ is a branching point of $p$, in particular it is in $p$. This means that all points of $q$ below its $n$th
 splitting level are in $p$ and because $p$ is a subset of $q$ this means that $p$ and $q$ are exactly the same below the $n$th splitting level of $q$. Therefore the $n$th splitting level of $q$ is also the $n$th splitting level of $p$.

As to the proof: prove that the $n$th splitting level of $p_n$ survives to become the $n$th splitting level of $p$.